# Socket.io: Server side emit doesn't send if it's a certain value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm working on a personal project currently and have ran into some trouble with socket.io

I'm trying to emit a socket from the server however, the socket is only delivered if the socket value/address is changed from `/lobby/invalid` to `/lobby/info`.

oh also, I'm using a MERN stack for this project.

**Server**

```
//# Loading a lobby
  socket.on(`/lobby/load`, async (req, res) => {
    let doesExist = (game.lobbies[req.id] !== undefined)
    // Return user if the lobby doesn't exist
    if(doesExist === false) {
      console.log(LogError(`Error: Lobby does not exist!`))
      console.log(socket.id)
      io.to(socket.id).emit(`/lobby/invalid`, {}) // This does NOT send unless I change the value to "/lobby/info"
      return
    } else { // if the lobby does exist cont.
        io.to(socket.id).emit(`/lobby/info`, { // THIS WORKS
          settings: game.lobbies[req.id].settings,
          players: game.lobbies[req.id].players,
          chat: game.lobbies[req.id].chat,
          game: game.lobbies[req.id].game,
        })
    }
  })
```

**Client**

```
componentDidMount() {
    let id = window.location.pathname
    id = id.substr(7)
    
    //# Lobby info request
    socket.emit(`/lobby/load`, { id: id, uid: cookies.get("id") })
    //# Lobby invalid await
    socket.on(`/lobby/invalid`, (data) => {
      console.error(`ERROR: Lobby doesnt' exist, RETURN`)
    })
    //# Lobby info waiter
    socket.on(`/lobby/info`, (data) => {
      this.setState(data)
      console.log(this.state)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you see the consoles from if statement?

Comment: Yeah, the console logs show up 100%, its just the io.emit just seems to only work if I use `/lobby/info`. Strange because all other socket calls work perfect, both client and server sided.

Comment: Just a wild guess : on the client have you tried adding the listeners **before** you emit `/lobby/load`?

Comment: you know that `io.emit(socket.id)` is actually `socket.emit`? Maybe try it like this and I'll write another approach that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey again so usally when I use socket.io with single user emit's I'm using callback approach which goes like following.

```js
// server side
socket.on(`/lobby/load`, (data, callback) => {
  let doesExist = (typeof game.lobbies[data.id] !== "undefined");
  let payload = {
    state: "invalid",
  };

  if(doesExist) {
    payload.state = "info";
    payload.settings = game.lobbies[data.id].settings;
    payload.players = game.lobbies[data.id].players;
    payload.chat = game.lobbies[data.id].chat;
    payload.game = game.lobbies[data.id].game;
  }

  // return the payload to user via callback
  callback(payload);

  process.nextTick(() => (payload = null));
  // null the payload reference so node's GC can clean up the memory :)
});
```

Please notice here that the callback should be the last thing to send, you can't send callback functions inside `payload` data

and for client side:

```js
socket.emit(`/lobby/load`, { id: id, uid: cookies.get("id") }, (payload) => {
  if (payload.state === "invalid") {
    return console.log("invalid game id!!");
  }

  this.setState(payload);
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

At the end with this approach you don't need to remove events that you listen when your component unmonth. :)

That's the main reason why I'm using this and also users can always open console and listen for your data when you send server side emit's :) (also prevents that since everything goes via a callback =)

With mentioned about sending callbacks it's actually called `ack` on the docs of socket.io which you can see here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/index.html#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack

Comment: Hello again, thanks so much for that reply. That's a much more efficient and cleaner way to do it anyways. I'll try it now then get back to you.

Comment: Currently not working that code, it's giving me this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function` (on the backend)

Comment: Hee bee, what are the versions you use?

Comment: Haii, I'm currently on version `^3.1.1`

Comment: Well it's also documented v3 docs, https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack and I'm using this approach but can you actually console everything on server side and see if callback comes with correct types??

Comment: All are correctly set. I'm going to try upgrading to v4 and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Made no difference switching to a newer version. Also a note, when I log `callback` it returns as `undefined`, so whatevers going on with my app is only sending one value/variable to socket. Still looking about now

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help hali. I fixed the issue by updating both the server and client sockets to the latest version. You're a gem <3

Comment: Glad to be able to help =) Also notice this approach only working with single socket connections, so if you need to send a room of connections you need to turn back to emitting events via `io.in('room').emit('event', with_your_data)`